Shopware 6: Upsert Media with Product
Is it possible to upsert a media file with a product upsert? Either as a separate payload in the same request or directly via the product upsert?
We have about 10k articles with images I want to sync. Optimal strategy would be to only update the image if the article is created (normally they don't change) and of course do everything in one go (like 100 products at a time).
What I have until now (using /vienthuong/shopware-php-sdk):
        $syncService = new SyncService($this->context);
        $payload = new SyncPayload();
        $payload->set(ProductDefinition::ENTITY_NAME . '-upsert', new SyncOperator(ProductDefinition::ENTITY_NAME, SyncOperator::UPSERT_OPERATOR, [
            [
                'id' => '018cf59aa9d870008000fbc39f0fcef2',
                'name' => 'New Product',
                'taxId' => '018de63f1b61715aad18389bfaddf6ba',
                'price' => [
                    [
                        'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
                        'linked' => true,
                        'gross' => 999.99,
                        'net' => (999.99 / 1.19),
                    ],
                ],
                'productNumber' => 'FRE832672',
                'stock' => 2,
                ],
        ]));

        echo("============================================");
        echo("Sync response");
        $response = $syncService->sync($payload);
        var_dump($response);

adding a property like
    'cover' => [
        'url' => 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/stock-photo-woman-with-static-electric-hair-isolated-on-black-background-250nw-2014152446.jpg',
        ],

doesn't work...

In Shopware, you cannot directly include media data within the product upsert payload. Media files are handled separately. There are two approaches:

Separate Requests with References

This sample code is for 'Separate Requests with References'
<?php

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Uuid\Uuid;
use Shopware\Core\Media\MediaDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Media\Service\MediaServiceInterface;

$syncService = new SyncService($this->context);
$mediaService = $this->container->get('media.service'); // Assuming MediaServiceInterface is injected

// Product Upsert
$payload = new SyncPayload();
$payload->set(ProductDefinition::ENTITY_NAME . '-upsert', new SyncOperator(ProductDefinition::ENTITY_NAME, SyncOperator::UPSERT_OPERATOR, [
    [
        'id' => '018cf59aa9d870008000fbc39f0fcef2', // Replace with actual ID (if updating)
        'name' => 'New Product',
        'taxId' => '018de63f1b61715aad18389bfaddf6ba',
        'price' => [
            [
                'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
                'linked' => true,
                'gross' => 999.99,
                'net' => (999.99 / 1.19),
            ],
        ],
        'productNumber' => 'FRE832672',
        'stock' => 2,
    ],
]));

echo("============================================");
echo("Sync response");
$response = $syncService->sync($payload);

// Check for successful product creation
if ($response->isSuccess()) {
  $productId = $response->getEntities()[ProductDefinition::ENTITY_NAME][0]['id'];

  // Media Upload (assuming URL upload)
  $mediaUrl = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/stock-photo-woman-with-static-electric-hair-isolated-on-black-background-250nw-2014152446.jpg';
  $mediaData = [
      'name' => 'Product Image for ' . $productId,
      'url' => $mediaUrl,
  ];

  $media = $mediaService->create($mediaData, Context::createDefaultContext());
  $mediaId = $media->getId();

  // Associate media with product (assuming relation exists)
  $productRepository = $this->container->get('product.repository');
  $updateData = [
      'id' => $productId,
      'coverId' => $mediaId, // Assuming 'coverId' is the relation field
  ];
  $productRepository->update([$updateData], Context::createDefaultContext());

  echo("Product created successfully and image uploaded with ID: " . $mediaId);
} else {
  echo("Error creating product: " . $response->getMessage());
}




Batch Processing with Media IDs

The provided vienthuong/shopware-php-sdk might not explicitly support batch product updates with media references, Shopware offers different approaches which helps you to achieve your goal:
a) Staged Updates with Separate Media Uploads: This approach involves creating/updating products first, followed by separate media uploads referencing the created product IDs.
b) Custom Development (if necessary): If Shopware's core functionalities don't meet your specific needs, you can consider doing custom development using the Shopware API to create a batch update endpoint that handles both products and media references.
The following code is for staged updates with seperate media uploads
<?php

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Uuid\Uuid;
use Shopware\Core\Media\MediaDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Media\Service\MediaServiceInterface;

$syncService = new SyncService($this->context);
$mediaService = $this->container->get('media.service'); // Assuming MediaServiceInterface is injected
$productRepository = $this->container->get('product.repository');

$products = [];
$mediaData = [];

// Prepare product data with temporary placeholder values for media IDs
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) { // Adjust loop for your data
  $productId = Uuid::randomBytes(); // Generate new ID for new product
  $products[] = [
      'id' => $productId,
      'name' => 'Product ' . ($i + 1),
      'taxId' => '018de63f1b61715aad18389bfaddf6ba',
      'price' => [
          [
              'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
              'linked' => true,
              'gross' => 999.99,
              'net' => (999.99 / 1.19),
          ],
      ],
      'productNumber' => 'FRE832672',
      'stock' => 2,
      // Placeholder for media ID (replace with actual ID after upload)
      'coverId' => null,
  ];

  // Prepare media data for separate upload (assuming URL upload)
  $mediaUrl = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/stock-photo-woman-with-static-electric-hair-isolated-on-black-background-250nw-2014152446.jpg';
  $mediaData[] = [
      'name' => 'Product Image for ' . $productId,
      'url' => $mediaUrl,
  ];
}

// 1. Create/Update Products
$productRepository->create($products, Context::createDefaultContext());

// 2. Upload Media and Associate with Products (after successful product creation)
$uploadedMedia = [];
foreach ($mediaData as $i => $media) {
  $uploadedMedia[$i] = $mediaService->create($media, Context::createDefaultContext());
}

// 3. Update Products with Media IDs (assuming relation exists)
$updatedProducts = [];
foreach ($products as $i => $product) {
  $updatedProducts[] = [
      'id' => $product['id'],
      'coverId' => $uploadedMedia[$i]->getId(), // Reference uploaded media ID
  ];
}
$productRepository->update($updatedProducts, Context::createDefaultContext());

echo("Products and media uploaded successfully!");


Try these approaches and it will solve your problem.
